# A sequence linked to irrationality

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, diophantine-approximation

Let $0 < c < 1$ be a real number and $ x \in \mathbb{R}$. We define the sequence $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ by :

$$u_0 = x$$
$$ \mathrm{If}, u_n \le c, \mathrm{then}, u_{n + 1} = u_n + (1 - c) $$
$$ \mathrm{If}, u_n > c, \mathrm{then}, u_{n + 1} = u_n - c $$

I'm studiying this sequence and my main issue is the following :
Let $N$ be a positive integer, i search $ \mathrm{min} \{u_n, n\le N\} $. Another interesting question i think, would be to compute this limit : $$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{ \mathrm{Card} \{ n \le N : u_n \ge c\}}{N} $$
I think, the main issue comes from the possibility of c being irrational

Is there already a study of this sequence? If not, which tools/theory could help me in studying this sequence?

Thank you for your attention

Comment: For large enough $n$ we have $u_n=\{x+nc\} $ (fractional part), such sequences are well studied. The limit you are looking for equals $1-c$ both if $c$ is irrational and not.

Comment: To be a bit more serviceable: read the first 10 or so pages in the book of Kuipers and Niederreiter: Uniform Distribution of Sequences. (Copy the title to google and you will find a pdf-file of the whole book.)